# Does an Elder Brain's Break Concentration work vs. Focused Conjuration?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, wizard

The conjuration wizard school has an ability named **Focused Conjuration**
which says

> Beginning at 10th level, while you are concentrating on a conjuration spell, your concentration can’t be broken as a result of taking damage.

The elder brain has the legendary action **Break Concentration** which says

> The elder brain targets a creature within 120 feet of it with which it has a psychic link. The elder brain breaks the creature's concentration on a spell it has cast. The creature also takes 1d4 psychic damage per level of the spell.

So if a wizard has the spell *conjure elemental* up and the elder brain uses its Legendary Action, is the wizard's concentration broken?

Answer (score 10):

## Yes, the concentration is broken.

**Focused Conjuration**

> Beginning at 10th level, while you are concentrating on a conjuration
> spell, your concentration can’t be broken **as a result of taking damage**

(emphasis mine)

Note that the ability only prevents breaking concentration "as a result of taking damage" and not from other causes.

**Break Concentraion**

> The elder brain targets a creature within 120 feet of it with which it
> has a psychic link. The elder brain breaks the creature's
> concentration on a spell it has cast. The creature also takes ld4
> psychic damage per level of the spell

Since the ability "Break Concentration" simply breaks concentration (and not as a result of damage) then it would still apply as normal.